# where is default template for link defined?

Tags: magento2, layout, theme, magento-2.0

Please look at this screenshot:

[image]

Then look at "Mi cuenta" and "Crear una cuenta" links. As you see, those don't have templates defined, and in fact, when I saw the XML for layout, there is no en explicit template definition. so the question is, where is the default template for link defined?

I looked at module-theme/view/frontend/templates/link.phml but it seems it is not used.

Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

jstuardo,

I don't speak Spanish, but I think that you are referring to the My Accounts and Create an Account links.

You can remove these from your magento skin/template by editing the layout/customer.xml file.

Additionally, if you wish to remove these from other areas, the layout.xml file can be edited to add "removeLinkByName" entries or by using an entry like this:

`<action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/></action>`

in the layout.xml file.

Keep in mind, you may have to change the url specified above if your url is different.

Comment: I don't want to remove the links, but change the HTML. But never mind, I have found that I needed to extend the block because it added the markup I needed to remove (tag UL)

Answer (score 0):

I have programmed this override:

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

namespace Desytec\Framework\View\Element\Html;

/**
 * Description of MenuUsuario
 *
 * @author Jaime Stuardo
 */
class MenuUsuario extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links {
    /**
     * Render block HTML
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        if (false != $this->getTemplate()) {
            return parent::_toHtml();
        }

        if ($this->getLinks()) {
            $html = '<div' . ($this->hasCssClass() ? ' class="' . $this->escapeHtml(
                $this->getCssClass()
            ) . '"' : '') . '>';
            foreach ($this->getLinks() as $link) {
                $html .= $this->renderLink($link);
            }
            $html .= '</div>';
        }

        return $html;
    }    
}
```

And in block definition, I have to set that class instead of default one:

```
                <container name="menu-top" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="menu-top">
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml" />
                    <block class="Desytec\Framework\View\Element\Html\MenuUsuario" name="top.links" template="">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">menu-usuario</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Desytec\Framework\View\Element\Html\MenuUsuario" name="top.links.responsive" template="">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">menu-usuario-responsive</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>                        
                </container>
```